# SQL Server finding percentage using already calculated total

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains Salary values and totals for each company. I want to find percentage and not sure how?

The `istotal` flag represents whether it is total or not; 0 means not total and 1 means total

```
create table work.temp
(
    empid int, 
    Salaryvalue float,
    istotal smallint
)

insert into work.temp 
values (1, 10.0, 0), (1, 20.0, 0), (1, 30.0, 0), (1, 60.0, 1)
```

This is the expected output:

```
create table work.output
(
    empid int, 
    salaryvalue float,
    issubtotal smallint,
    percentage float
)

insert into work.output 
values (1, 10.0, 16.6),  --(10.0/60.0)*100
       (1, 20.0, 33.3),  --(20.0/60.0)*100
       (1, 30.0, 50.0),  --(30.0/60.0)*100
       (1, 60.0, 100.0)  --(60.0/60.0)*100
```

Not quite sure how to do it

Thanks mr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the `SalaryValue` total for each `empid` on every row using windowed aggregates (The `isnull nullif` pair is there to handle divide by zero errors):

```
declare @t table(empid int,SalaryValue float,istotal smallint);
insert into @t values(1, 10.0, 0), (1, 20.0, 0), (1, 30.0, 0), (1, 60.0, 1);

select empid
        ,SalaryValue
        ,istotal
        ,isnull(SalaryValue / nullif(sum(case when istotal = 1 then SalaryValue else 0 end) over (partition by empid),0),0) as Percentage
from @t;
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
| empid | SalaryValue | istotal |    Percentage     |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
|     1 |          10 |       0 | 0.166666666666667 |
|     1 |          20 |       0 | 0.333333333333333 |
|     1 |          30 |       0 |               0.5 |
|     1 |          60 |       1 |                 1 |
+-------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
```

---

Alternatively, you could join the table to itself with one version returning `istotal = 1` and the other `istotal = 0`:

```
declare @t table(empid int,SalaryValue float,istotal smallint);
insert into @t values(1, 10.0, 0), (1, 20.0, 0), (1, 30.0, 0), (1, 60.0, 1);

with t as
(
    select empid
            ,SalaryValue
    from @t
    where istotal = 1
)
select s.empid
        ,s.SalaryValue
        ,t.SalaryValue as Total
        ,isnull(s.SalaryValue / nullif(t.SalaryValue,0),0) as Percentage
from @t as s
    left join t
        on s.empid = t.empid
where s.istotal = 0;
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------+-------+-------------------+
| empid | SalaryValue | Total |    Percentage     |
+-------+-------------+-------+-------------------+
|     1 |          10 |    60 | 0.166666666666667 |
|     1 |          20 |    60 | 0.333333333333333 |
|     1 |          30 |    60 |               0.5 |
+-------+-------------+-------+-------------------+
```